# Crypto Random get_random_bytes is not working in py3 as it did in py2

Tags: python, python-3.4, pycrypto

This code used to work in py2.  In py3 I get this:

[image: console]

Here is the code:

```
from Crypto import Random
import os

def generate_random_bytes(length):
    return Random.get_random_bytes(length)
    #return bytearray(os.urandom(length))  I tried this line but got the same result

def generate_server_id():
    """Generates 20 random hex characters"""
    print(generate_random_bytes(10))
    print(ord(c) for c in generate_random_bytes(10))
    return "".join("%02x" % ord(c) for c in generate_random_bytes(10))
```

Comment: replace `ord(c)` with just `c`, in Py3 a byte array item is already an integer instead of a character, so you don't need the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `ord(c)` with `c`, in Py3 a byte array item is already an integer instead of a character, so you don't need the conversion.

You may want to rewrite it like this, in order to make it work on both versions:

```
def generate_server_id():
    """Generates 20 random hex characters"""
    try:
        return "".join("%02x" % ord(c) for c in generate_random_bytes(10))
    except TypeError:
        return "".join("%02x" % c for c in generate_random_bytes(10))
```

Comment: `six.iterbytes` (if you have six as a dependency) is a potentially better option

Comment: Sure it looks more elegant, but I would not say "better" because better depends heavily on the context.

Comment: well in python3 your code as written does the following: calls generate_random_bytes once, raises an exception, calls it again.  That's twice as much work as it needs to do *and* it needs to do exception handling :)

Comment: Indeed, but this is not a big deal unless you are generating a lot of server ids... :-) BTW the OP may be interested into the `uuid` module.

Comment: Thanks very much.. I actually define a PY3 constant in the import area based on Importerror's... so I could just 'if PY3:' -- thanks!  I'll try this out!